# Razor, MVC4, @html.dropdownlistfor problems

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a drop down list that populates from a database. I have:

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String JobTitle { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String ProjectName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectHour
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal Hours { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> employeeId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> projectId { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want is to create a form that will create new project hours associated with a project and an employee. I'm trying to use dropdownlists to display the employees and the projects on the create form. Obviously, I'm completely new at this, but what I have so far is:

```
[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult CreateProjectHour(ProjectHour newProjectHour)
     {
             using (var db = new TimesheetContext())
             {
                 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> emp = db.Employees
                  .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                      Text = c.LastName
                  });
                 ViewBag.EmployeeId = emp;

                 db.ProjectHours.Add(newProjectHour);
                 db.SaveChanges();
             }

             return RedirectToAction("ProjectHourList");
         }
     }
```

And on the form:

```
@model TimesheetMVC.Models.ProjectHour
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.employeeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeId)
```

Which is apparently horribly wrong. Any help would be much appreciated...!

Comment: Oh, this is the error it gives when rendering
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Id'.

Comment: using static DDLHelper class it's easy way to [bind drop down check this](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2013/06/bind-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use the same name EmployeeId. You need 2 things to create a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC: a scalar property that will hold the selected value and a collection property that will contain the possible values. But since you are using the ViewBag (which I totally recommend against) you could do the following:

```
ViewBag.Employees = emp;
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.employeeId, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Employees
)
```

But as I said this is not at all an approach that I recommend. I recommend using view models. So define an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property on your view model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employees { get; set; }
```

and in your controller populate this view model property and then make your view strongly typed to the view model.

Comment: I tried your solution that you totally recommend against, and it still gives the same error, "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'employeeId'. ". On a side note: why do you recommend against it?

Comment: Do you have the same code that populates `ViewBag.Employees` in your GET action? Because what you have shown is your POST action. I recommend against it because it is good practice to use strongly typed view models in ASP.NET MVC instead of passing your domain models to the view and then using weakly typed ViewBag/ViewData. Those are 2 different sources to pass information to the view which violates the pattern.

Comment: I fixed a small amount of my stupidity, and moved the code to the GET action.... but now I get: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Comment: Yeah, that's because of the lazy loading nature of EF. You should make it eager by calling `.ToList()` inside the controller action: `ViewBag.Employees = emp.ToList();`. This will force an eager load inside the db context.

Comment: Thanks for all your help... but now: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. "

Comment: Yes, yes, all this is EF specific stuff, nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. Here's what to do: `db.Employees.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id.ToString(), Text = c.LastName });`. Notice the `.ToList()` call after `db.Employees`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I apologize for my ignorance, I know I have a lot to learn about EF.

Answer (score 9):

Or you could just do a 
in the controller

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(db.Employees, "Id", "LastName");
ViewBag.EmployeeList = selectList;
```

and in the View

```
@Html.DropDownBoxFor(model => model.id_Employee, ViewBag.EmployeeList as SelectList)
```

I find this approach easier.

Answer (score 0):

`EmployeeId` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not a `SelectList`.
Therefore, your cast cannot work.

You need to explicitly create a `SelectList`.

Comment: Not true. The `DropdownListFor` helper signature says it expects an enumerable of `SelectListItem`, so you could pass a `List`, `Collection1`, or any custom derivative of `IEnumerable` so long as it was packed with the right item types.